# Expected Number of Triangles

Tags: pr.probability, geometric-probability

A unit square is divided up with $n$ random lines. The random lines are chosen as follows, we choose one side of the square and pick a random point on that side. From there we choose a random point on one of the three other sides and connect the points. We then continue this process $n$ times.

After $n$ random lines what is the expected number of quadrilaterals formed?

Comment: Your title says "triangles" and your question says "quadrilaterals".  Also, there is more than one way to count.  Please clarify.

Comment: Surely you mean polygons, not triangles or quadrilaterals? Of course you can decompose any polynomial into triangles. Is that what you mean? If this is so then a good place to start might be the number of subdivisions of the lines, since each subdivision is used exactly twice as the edge of a polygon, one on each side.

Comment: Yes, I believe I mean polygons and not quadrilaterals. Also the triangles in the title was an error.